# Laravel backend API, react frontend login

Tags: reactjs, laravel, oauth-2.0, oauth, laravel-7

I am trying to do the following:

1. User clicks a link to URL site from react (say google.com)
2. User enters his credentials on a pop-up form [using react's simple oauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-oauth2-login#basic-example)

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import OAuth2Login from 'react-simple-oauth2-login';
     
    const onSuccess = response => console.log(response);
    const onFailure = response => console.error(response);
     
    ReactDOM.render(
      <OAuth2Login
        authorizationUrl="https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"
        responseType="token"
        clientId="9822046hvr4lnhi7g07grihpefahy5jb"
        redirectUri="http://localhost:3000/oauth-callback"
        onSuccess={onSuccess}
        onFailure={onFailure}/>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

3. The site returns to me a JSON with the users data (on a specific URL user/callback)

Laravel (after the callback is read from my routes file) does the following:

```
    public function handleProviderCallBackMel(Request $request)
    {    
       return reponse()->json($jsonUser,200);
    }
```

That's working A-OK with Laravel. Laravel get the response (the token and the user data that I need). BUT I can't pass that information back to react.

How do I pass that data to my front end react app from my backend laravel app that got the callback information I need?

Comment: you should pass the data on your callback endpoint the `then()` method should pass the data when received

Comment: @Doggo but how will laravel will be able to return my data to the react application? They are two different applications. Should I make react somehow "await" for a response?

Comment: if you only have 1 backend you can listen to the data. If you are using `axios` it will return a promise you can also try async await.

Comment: @Doggo I think I added some information that might be useful

Comment: I think you should get the data on the `onSuccess` function try to `console.log(response)` then check your console log in the browser

Comment: @Doggo this is true. However the data are returned from Laravel like I showed above BUT the oauth component doesn't seem to understand that Laravel processed the request and now returned a token. How do I make React understand that everything went ok? It just hangs there with a pop up

Comment: `const onSuccess = response => { showModal(); console.log('success') };` you shound make a function in the `onSuccess` to show it in the front end

Comment: or try to save the token and redirect the user somewhere else `const onSuccess = response => { localStorage.set('token', response.token); window.location.replace("https://www.google.com"); console.log('success') };`

Comment: The problem is that react is receiving a success message from Laravel. Is that a problem with my Laravel code?

Comment: maybe on your callback function you should return the json data try `return response()->json(['data' => $request], 200)`

Comment: @Doggo that was the first I did at first. However, React cannot "fetch" the data that laravel returned. I was thinking if there is a way to POST back the data from Laravel to React?

Comment: I think you need a listener